# UIAlertController: make disappear a message after 3 seconds

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I wanted to know how to make disappear a message after 3 seconds ?
Thanks,

```
    UIAlertController *alert_carbu_reglementaire = [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"ATTENTION"
                              message:@"Le résultat ne prend pas en compte la quantité réglementaire"
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

     [self presentViewController:alert_carbu_reglementaire animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: In the completion of `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead of putting `nil`, you could dismiss it there after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

There are two useful tools at your disposal: the first is that you can easily delay execution with one of the `performSelector` methods like this:

```
// after present, wait 3 seconds and perform a selector
[self presentViewController:alert_carbu_reglementaire animated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissTheAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

The second is that fact that view controllers may dismiss vcs presented atop them (and anything presented above those) with `dismisViewController...`

```
- (void) dismissTheAlert {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. With the simulator, when a touch on the button, the message appear and disappear immediately -_-

Comment: I tested it before posting.  Worked fine.  It implies that some other code in your app is running to dismiss the alert sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GC power to call setMessage after 3 sec.
Look at this example:

Swift 2.3

```
let delay = 3.0
let delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

dispatch_after(delayInNanoSeconds, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    alert_carbu_reglementaire.message = ""
}
```

Objective-C

```
double delay = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [alert_carbu_reglementaire setMessage:@""];
});
```

Be sure that you don't create memory leak.

Comment: It's Obj C ?? or Swift ?

Comment: It is swift example but you can simple translate it on objective.

double delay = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [alert_carbu_reglementaire setMessage:@""];
});

Comment: Note*
This core clear message after delay. If you can hide controller - you can call dissmissViewController to remove VC from screen.